# How to make oval shape with 20 straight lines repeatable?

Tags: python, algorithm

I need to create this shape for a patchwork program that repeats the patch in a specific pattern. Im not sure where to start to create this since it only uses 20 straight lines so any help would be fantastic.

[image]

Comment: Have a close look of the coordinates of the segments...

Answer (score 1):

It is actually a math series. Just look at lines start and end points and how they increase and decrease you can find a solution.

```
s = 1000
img = np.full((s,s,3), 255, dtype='uint8')
inc = 10

color = [0,0,255]
for i,j in zip(range(0,s+1,inc), range(0,s+1,inc)):
    cv2.line(img, (i,1), (s,i), color, 2)
    cv2.line(img, (1,j), (j,s), color, 2)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a set of lines to draw:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int

@dataclass
class Line:
    p1: Point
    p2: Point

def lower_left_mesh(height, width, n):
    return [
        Line(
            Point(0, i * (height - 1) // n),
            Point((i + 1) * (width - 1) // n, height - 1)
        )
        for i in range(n)
    ]
```

So, for instance:

```
>>> lower_left_mesh(101, 101, 10)

[Line(p1=Point(x=0, y=0),  p2=Point(x=10, y=100)),
 Line(p1=Point(x=0, y=10), p2=Point(x=20, y=100)),
 Line(p1=Point(x=0, y=20), p2=Point(x=30, y=100)),
 Line(p1=Point(x=0, y=30), p2=Point(x=40, y=100)),
 Line(p1=Point(x=0, y=40), p2=Point(x=50, y=100)),
 Line(p1=Point(x=0, y=50), p2=Point(x=60, y=100)),
 Line(p1=Point(x=0, y=60), p2=Point(x=70, y=100)),
 Line(p1=Point(x=0, y=70), p2=Point(x=80, y=100)),
 Line(p1=Point(x=0, y=80), p2=Point(x=90, y=100)),
 Line(p1=Point(x=0, y=90), p2=Point(x=100, y=100))]
```